# Having issues placing html buttons side by side in a form

Tags: html, css, forms, button

this is my first question here.

I'm having an issue getting my html form buttons side by side.. can somebody take a look and tell me whats wrong? it'd seem like they should by default be placed inline, but I guess that isnt the case.

Here is my html code.

```
        <input type="submit" name="1" formtarget="" value="1">
        <input type="submit" name="2" formtarget="" value="2">
        <input type="submit" name="3" formtarget="" value="3">
        <input type="submit" name="4" formtarget="" value="4">
```

and here is the CSS for the form input and individual name

```
#form input {
position: relative;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
text-shadow: none;
line-height: 44px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

and this is the same for each button besides the color changes.

```
#form input[name="1"] {
margin-top: 8px;
height: 44px;
width: 50%;
background: #A901DB;
border-bottom: 1px solid #B404AE;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
}
#form input[name="2"] {
margin-top: 8px;
height: 44px;
width: 50%;
background: #A901DB;
border-bottom: 1px solid #B404AE;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Can someone help me set this up so that they are inline, side by side?

EDIT: This is what it shows.

http://jsfiddle.net/g01juc2z/2/

Comment: What do they look like to you? They seem ok

Comment: Seems fine to me, tested in Chrome just now.

Comment: Aside from the 100% width button, the others are side by side http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g01juc2z/. Oh wait, are you saying you made each button 100% width?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I didnt mean to have it set at 100%, its supposed to be at 50.. ill post what happens for me. See, Look here... http://jsfiddle.net/g01juc2z/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 4 elements set to `width:50%` which equals 200% width. Change them to `width: 24%` (`inline-block` elements have a natural spacing of 1 or 2px) or less and they will be aligned:

```
#form input[name="1"] {
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: 44px;
  width: 24%; <---------------
  background: #A901DB;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B404AE;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g01juc2z/6/)

Answer (score 0):

in your css make these change where you write

```
[name="1"]
```

replace it with

```
[type="submit"]
```

and do not repeat it like a name 
and another change is

```
width:24%;
```